# How to do this kind of query?

Tags: sql

A **user** can have **suspensions**. I want to select a **user** and his **suspensions**, but I only want the suspensions where the **suspensions.suspended_date > now()**. I want to return the user regardless.

It sounds like a left join, but:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
LEFT JOIN suspensions ON suspensions.user_id=users.id
WHERE suspensions.suspended_date > now()
```

Would work fine if they DO have suspensions, but would cause trouble if they don't have any, because the where clause would always fail.

How can I write this with one query?

Comment: the WHERE filters the final result set, throwing away rows where there are no suspensions. by moving your where condition into the join, you allow the LEFT JOIN to work as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try moving the filter from the WHERE to the JOIN statement

```
SELECT *
FROM   users 
       LEFT JOIN suspensions 
       ON suspensions.user_id=users.id AND suspensions.suspended_date > now()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM users
LEFT JOIN suspensions ON suspensions.user_id=users.id
WHERE suspensions.suspended_date > now() or suspensions.suspended_date is null
```

That should do it.

Comment: This won't work because an absent suspension isn't "null"..it's just nonexistant.

Comment: When a left join doesn't match null will show up for the columns that are in the table that didn't match the join clause.

Comment: Hmm..it doesn't in Postgres. Which DB does that work for you in?

Comment: That's interesting. Did you try my query in Postgres? I looked up the documentation and my syntax looks like it works there too. It works in tSQL and MySQL (as I recall).

Comment: Yeah, I tried it in postgres, copied and pasted. I didn't get a result. I mean of course a left join fills the nonexistant right table with nulls, but it looks like it doesn't treat unmatched right rows as nulls until after the query is done. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
LEFT JOIN suspensions ON suspensions.user_id=users.id
WHERE suspensions.suspended_date > now() or suspensions.user is null
```